# How do you theme specific fields in on a content type?

Tags: 7, theming

Currently I want to theme a taxonomy field in my content type and expose the TID and the Term name with link. The default sections only give me one or the other. Is there a setup where I can expose the TID, Term name, and Link?

Below is a screenshot of the teaser view display mode.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use [field.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!theme!field.tpl.php/7)

If your field is called **field_series** then you will need to create:

/mytheme/anyfolder(optional)/field--field-series.tpl.php

If you inspect the variable $element then it will contain everything you'll need (tid, name, see [drupal_get_path_alias](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_get_path_alias/7) for the link)

Don't forget to clear the cache once the new template has been created.

Answer (score 1):

Felix is right on. If you want a UI for this for some help and flexability look at [Fences](https://drupal.org/project/fences).

> **What it's doing**
>
> Behind the scenes, the Fences module is remembering which custom tpl
>   file you want to use for each field. This is set in the field
>   configuration itself — not in the display (or view mode)
>   configuration. That way, every time to output this field, it will use
>   this custom tpl.
>
> Fences ships with a bunch of tpls files. Look inside the module to see
>   which ones, and to see the markup for each of those. If you would like
>   to change that markup, make a copy of any tpl file, put it in your
>   custom theme, and edit away. Drupal will automatically use the copy in
>   your theme instead of the copy in the Fences module files (once you
>   clear the cache).
>
> If you would like to make more things — and add to the list of
>   possibilities — make more tpls files of your own, and place them in
>   your theme. Use the fences naming convention, and Fences will
>   automatically find them, and add them to the list available in the
>   dropdown for field configuration.

Or jump in and try out [DisplaySuite](https://drupal.org/project/ds) which allows you to customize fields, or whole Node displays ...

> Display Suite allows you to take full control over how your content is
>   displayed using a drag and drop interface. Arrange your nodes, views,
>   comments, user data etc. the way you want without having to work your
>   way through dozens of template files. A predefined list of layouts (D7
>   only) is available for even more drag and drop fun!
>
> By defining custom view modes (build modes in D6), you can define how
>   one piece of content should be displayed in different places such as
>   teaser lists, search results, the full node, views etc.